# Classic ASP writing csv file, not writing data to separate columns

Tags: file-io, csv, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP script creating a CSV file, but it isn't writing correctly to separate columns.  It's basically writing it all to the first column.

```
dim filesavepath
filesavepath =  site_pathRoot & "dynamic/pdf/" & fileName & ".csv"

set FSO = Server.CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")

set csvfile = FSO.CreateTextFile(filesavepath, true,true)

csvfile.writeLine(Head)
```

Where head is a variable as such

```
Head = "Date, Name, Recipe Name, Email, Joined Mailing List?, Site, Suggestion Content"
```

If I use

```
set csvfile = FSO.CreateTextFile(filesavepath, true)
```

It works but I needed to use

```
set csvfile = FSO.CreateTextFile(filesavepath, true,true)
```

a while back because I need to write foreign symbols in the CSV.  Surely there must be a way to keep this and keep the columns intact?

Comment: when you say "it works", do you mean it loads correctly into a spreadsheet, such as Excel? I think Excel might interpret unicode files as binary (or, a different format at least). Anyroad, the commas will still be there: in Excel, select the leftmost column and use Data -> Text-to-Columns

Comment: yeah it loads in the spreadsheet but every row is loaded in the first column. So the issue is only a presentation one that im trying to fix

Answer (score 2):

As you have double quotes at the start and end of your data line the whole line is interpreted as one field.

Answer (score 0):

Done a bit of digging, and although it's a bit counter-intuative, but if you delimit your fields with the TAB character, then Excel seems to parse out Unicode files quite nicely. e.g. this works for me:

```
dim filesavepath
filename = "bla"
filesavepath =  fileName & ".csv"
QUOT = """"
COMMA = "   " '//this is now a TAB character
Head = "Date    Name"
line1 = "2001-01-01" & COMMA & QUOT & "Frank" & QUOT
line2 = "2002-01-01" & COMMA & QUOT & "Jan" & QUOT

set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")

set csvfile = FSO.CreateTextFile(filesavepath, true, true)

csvfile.writeLine(Head)
csvfile.writeLine(line1)
csvfile.writeLine(line2)
csvfile.writeLine(QUOT)
csvfile.close
```

Hope this helps.